# Does Blender still render while off of the screen?

Tags: rendering

So, I'm off of the Blender Program (not closed, but clicked off.) Does it still render at the same speed compared to if you were still on the screen?

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

[image: Rendered with blender on screen, 22 seconds]
[image: Rendered with blender iconified, 22 seconds]

I tested it several times, and observed variations of ±1 second for both of them, so it seems unlikely that the .14 second difference is of any significance.

However, if you use the computer for other things while rendering, *that* could impact the speed.

[image: Rendered while playing a youtube video, 33 seconds]

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you render from the command line, you usually get a little bit of a performance improvement in render speed since Blender doesn't waste any time/resources loading/updating the GUI.